# Laravel versão 5.8 não vem com a pasta routers?

Tags: php, laravel, instalador

Instalei o Laravel no meu servidor (que foi upado com vangrant e Virtual Box), mas não veio a pasta routers, que achei bem estranho, li pela documentação que ele vem com routers normais...

O que pode ser? Quando vou instalar dá os seguintes erros:

```
The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

PHP Warning:  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 952

Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 952

  [ErrorException]
  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
```

E esse aviso também aparece:

```
As there is no 'unzip' command installed zip files are being unpacked using the PHP zip extension.
This may cause invalid reports of corrupted archives. Besides, any UNIX permissions (e.g. executable) defined in the archives will be lost.
Installing 'unzip' may remediate them.
```

1. Qual a solução?
2. Por quê isso acontece?

OBS: Essa pergunta é parecida com a que eu fiz ([Como atualizar meu PHP para versão mais recente entrando pelo SSH no meu servidor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/384500/como-atualizar-meu-php-para-vers%C3%A3o-mais-recente-entrando-pelo-ssh-no-meu-servido))

Comment: Qual motivo dos votos negativos?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você deve instalar o pacote unzip em seu servidor, de acordo com as mensagens seu servidor pode estar sofrendo com falta de memoria:

> proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate 
>   memory

Answer (score 0):

Composer erro "proc_open(): fork failed errors#"

If composer shows proc_open() fork failed on some commands:

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory' in phar

Abaixo eu coloquei o link que fala sobre esse erro:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors

Na minha máquina virtual utilizando Ubuntu 18.04 eu resolvi utilizando os comandos abaixo na linha de comando.

**Solução que apliquei:**

$ sudo /bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024

$ sudo /sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1

$ sudo /sbin/swapon /var/swap.1